# Error with css floating for 3 elements in a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a rework on a website which includes adding a company's logo in-between 2 pieces of text for the navigation bar.

A problem I run into is that, while the original pieces of text have different div id's and are floating in opposite directions (one is floating left, and the other right), when I add the logo as an '', it off-puts the text floating to the right of the screen.

The text on the right would not only display on the next line but there was some issues with the image floating to the center where I had originally planned it to be.

I tried using 'display: flex;' on the container element, and while this sorted the issue of everything being on the same line, the image remained planted beside the text on the left and was not floating to the center. Additionally I tried using '' on the '' of the logo in the html but it remained put.

Next I tried using 'display: inline;' and 'display: inline-block;'. While they did work as an alternative to using 'display: flex;', they posed as inline properties which again, posed issues for the positioning of the image.

Below I have some pictures of my issue with the black box representing text and the dark green representing the logo.

[text floating underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlgDJ.png)

[logo stuck beside text on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NptoX.png)

The code currently being used:

```css
#topleft {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

#topmiddle {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

#topright {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="topleft">
  <h2>-------------</h2>
</div>

<div id="topmiddle">
  <img src="./img/logo.png">
</div>

<div id="topright">
  <h2>-------------</h2>
</div>
```

[what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwSVr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#topleft {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

#topmiddle {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

#topright {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
#nav{
width:100%;
height:auto;
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<div id="topleft">
  <h2>-------------</h2>
</div>

<div id="topmiddle">
  <img src="./img/logo.png">
</div>

<div id="topright">
  <h2>-------------</h2>
</div>
</div>
```